# Apache POI copy one row from Excel file to another new Excel File

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using JAVA 8 and Apache POI 3.17. I have an Excel file and i want to keep only few lines and delete the others. But my Excel have 40K rows and deleting them one by one is quite long (nearly 30 min :/ )

So i try to change my way of doing it. Now i think it's better to only take rows that i need in the excel source and copy to another new one. But what i have tried so far is not efficient.

I have all my rows and want to keep in a List. But this not working and create me a blank excel :

```
public void createExcelFileFromLog (Path logRejetFilePath, Path fichierInterdits) throws IOException {

Map<Integer, Integer> mapLigneColonne = getRowAndColumnInError(logRejetFilePath);

Workbook sourceWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fichierInterdits.toAbsolutePath().toString()));

Sheet sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

List<Row> listLignes = new ArrayList<Row>();

// get Rows from source Excel
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mapLigneColonne.entrySet()) {
    listLignes.add(sourceSheet.getRow(entry.getKey()-1));
}

// The new Excel
Workbook workbookToWrite = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheetToWrite = workbookToWrite.createSheet("Interdits en erreur");

// Copy Rows
Integer i = 0;
for (Row row : listLignes) {
    copyRow(sheetToWrite, row, i);
    i++;
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(config.getDossierTemporaire() + "Interdits_en_erreur.xlsx");
workbookToWrite.write(fos);
workbookToWrite.close();
sourceWorkbook.close();
}

private static void copyRow(Sheet newSheet, Row sourceRow, int newRowNum) {

Row newRow = newSheet.createRow(newRowNum);
newRow = sourceRow;
}
```

EDIT : Change the method of copyRow it's better but the date have weird format and blank cells from the original row are gone.

```
private static void copyRow(Sheet newSheet, Row sourceRow, int newRowNum) {

    Row newRow = newSheet.createRow(newRowNum);
    Integer i = 0;

    for (Cell cell : sourceRow) {

        if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 : To keep blank cell

```
private static void copyRow(Sheet newSheet, Row sourceRow, Integer newRowNum, Integer cellToColor) {

    Row newRow = newSheet.createRow(newRowNum);
    //Integer i = 0;

    int lastColumn = Math.max(sourceRow.getLastCellNum(), 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++) {
        Cell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

        if(oldCell == null) {
            newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue("");
        } else if (oldCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(oldCell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `copyRow` method you're creating a new row `newRow` and then setting that to `sourceRow` which does not change the values of the row that's newly added. Also this is taking 30 minutes? There's not *too* much going on

Comment: This (my code written) doesn't take 30 minutes but deleting each line yes. That's why i want to copy good row to another excel.

Comment: Better like i did in the EDIT but still have issues with date (format non kept) and blank cell (i want to have blank cell for certain colum like the original file)

Comment: just one more way to achieve this... instead of deletion of rows one by one... why not try to shift the rows. This will help you to keep your formatting as it is.

`shiftRows(fromRowNum, toRowNum, shiftByIndex)`

Comment: EDIT 2 : I change the code to get blank cell, now it's just the format date problem and all will be OK. @Sankumarsingh, i will try to shift rows i want to first place to see if it's better.

Comment: @Siick: A generic solution for all type of cell data... If you do not have much cells to copy then, have you tried to copy the cell style from source Cell to destination cell? I hope it should work.

`CellStyle destCellStyle = destWorkbook.createCellStyle();
destCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceCell.getCellStyle());`

and at the end apply this cell style to destination cell

`destCell.setCellStyle(destCellStyle);`

Comment: How about you use `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();` to convert all cell type to string so you can store all the blank cell as empty string.